# Use NTLM/Basic Auth in WebView. Objective-C/Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, basic-authentication

I'm making an iOS app, and I'm using an UIWebView to show a site, and everything seems to be working fine.

But when I go to a page of this site that require **HTTP Authentication (Basic/NTLM Auth, HTTP)** it does not work fine.

I was reading and I found a method `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` that indicate when is necessary Authentication in a page.

I found a example provided by Apple **(but it does not work for me)**. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
        newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[self preferencesName]
                                                 password:[self preferencesPassword]
                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
               forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        // inform the user that the user name and password
        // in the preferences are incorrect
        [self showPreferencesCredentialsAreIncorrectPanel:self];
    }
}
```

I was doing the same testing In **Android** and I found that We can use this method (It works for me):

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
    handler.proceed(username, password);
    ...
}
```

My question is, What is the correctly way to do **HTTP Authentication (Basic Auth, HTTP)** in objective-C ?

I did a test with two apps(android and IOS) for the same WebSite so Android app works fine, but the iOS app not.

Any advice will be use full for me!

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223494/uiwebview-sharepoint-ntlm-auth-i-get-stream-is-sending-an-event-before-bei This issue is like it.